# What is the role of += when concatenating two strings? (Eloquent JS FizzBuzz)

Tags: javascript, string, fizzbuzz

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
  var output = "";
  if (n % 3 == 0)
    output += "Fizz";
  if (n % 5 == 0)
    output += "Buzz";
  console.log(output || n);
}
```

Can someone explain how the += operator preceeding "Fizz" and "Buzz" plays a role in the concatentation of FizzBuzz when numbers are divisible by both 3 and 5?

My initial code was the following, which produced the same result:

```
 for (var number = 1; number <= 100; number++) 

 if (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0) {
    number == console.log("FizzBuzz");
 }

 else if (number % 3 == 0) {
    number == console.log("Fizz");
 }

 else if (number % 5 == 0) {
    number == console.log("Buzz");
 }

 else {
    console.log(number);
 }
```

Comment: it is the equivalent of `output = output + "Buzz";` (or Fizz)

Comment: += concatenating the string to the output... "Fizz"+"Buzz" == "FizzBuzz"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output += "Fizz";
```

is just the shorthand version of

```
output = output + "Fizz";
```

It will concatenate the value in `output` with `Fizz`, *create a new string* and store it back in `output`.

The important thing is, it creates a new String object, because String objects are immutable.

As per the logic, if the number is divisible by `3`, then `output` will become `Fizz`, since it is already empty. And if the number is also divisible by `5`, the `output` will become `FizzBuzz` (`Fizz + Buzz`).

Comment: is it immutable even for a JavaScript object?

Comment: @ochi Yes, JavaScript Strings are immutables.

Answer (score 0):

```
output += "Fizz";
```

is shorthand for

```
output = output + "Fizz";
```

Keeping a variable `output` allows for the case where both "Fizz" and "Buzz" are applicable to the number in the loop iteration and need to be combined.
`output` gets reset every loop.